# Restore original lodash method overwritten by mixin?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, lodash

We're using the `lodash-contrib` package, which includes a `camelCase` method that behaves differently than the original `_.camelCase` method.

Is there any way for me to restore the pointer to the original method?

In the requirejs config, we have a shim:

```
lodashContrib: ['lodash']
```

As soon as lodashContrib has loaded, it's added mixins to lodash. An example of our code:

```
define([
    'lodashContrib'
], function() {
    // our code here. At this point, _.camelCase is overridden by contrib
});
```

Comment: Is this node.js or requirejs?

Comment: RequireJS, so I can intercept the original lodash method before loading contrib.

Comment: Did you `browserify` it? Because it says it's only available for node unless you do that. If you're just loading the `lodash-contrib` libraries separately then you can just leave out the one that includes the `camelCase` implementation you don't like.

Comment: We're not using browserify (or webpack) so we really don't have any control over the build, but unfortunately, the code we do need is in the exact same file as the camelCase we don't.

Comment: Could you then provide the relevant code to demonstrate exactly how `lodash` and `lodash-contrib` are being loaded into the environment?

Comment: Updated with sample code

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `lodashCustom.js` or something you can add to your requirejs configuration, and put the following inside it, then wherever you require `lodashContrib` you can require this instead:

```
define(['lodash', 'lodashContrib'], function(_, _c) {
  _c.camelCase = _.camelCase;

  return _c;
});
```

Assuming your shim implementation doesn't rely on globals, this should hopefully work fine.

Comment: lodash-contrib doesn't get passed in as an argument, so `_` is already modified by the time it's loaded.

Comment: That's a contradictory claim to your example code, which you provided. `lodashContrib` was the only argument to that module. What's more is what you're saying now suggests that your shim relies on globals, which defeats the modularization that `requirejs` provides. Problems like this is the whole reason modularization is important to have.

Comment: There's no argument to the `define` callback in my example code, because `lodash-contrib` must not export one - it was always undefined. Lodash *does*, so until we moved to lodash-contrib, we did have such an argument. I haven't instructed requirejs or anything to behave like this.

Comment: I'm not sure how your `lodashContrib` module is written, but what it should do is accept `lodash` as an argument and return the modified `_`. Unless you want to go through the `lodash` source and copy / paste all the relevant scoped functions used to define `_.camelCase` I suggest you rewrite `lodashContrib` to behave in this manner.

Comment: I have no control over how it's written, https://github.com/TheNodeILs/lodash-contrib

Comment: Then perhaps you should copy and paste the other functions you do need from `lodashContrib` into `lodashCustom` and remove the `lodashContrib` module entirely.